# Is there a way to pass a variable to an exported generator from a different module in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, generator

I am writing a code which has two modules. I am trying to pass a variable from the first module as a parameter in the second module's generator function.

This is how my code looks so far.
I am trying to console.log `one` in the second module's generator (function*) function:

Module 2::

```
var fn = function* () {

     yield console.log(one);

     yield console.log('done');
}

var gen = fn();


module.exports = {gen}
```

Module 1::

```
var app = require('./app');
var one = 1;

app.gen.next(one);
app.gen.next();
```

I have tried passing one as a parameter in `fn()` as well as in `function* ()`, but that didn't work.

The output I expect to see from the console logs in the second module is ::

```
1
done
```

Comment: Why not simply export the generator *function* instead of exporting the generator object?

Comment: @Bergi that's correct, that's what I did in the revised code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your responses. I finally figured out the error in my code. My mistake was declaring `var gen = fn();` in the wrong module; it was supposed to be declared in module1 as follows:

```
var app = require('./app');
var one = 1;
var gen = app.fn(one); // First correction made here

gen.next();
gen.next();
```

In my revised code, I declared it in module1 and passed `one` as a parameter through it, which will then be accessed in module2  as:

```
var fn = function* (one) {... // Second correction made here
```

Then exported the generator function instead of exporting the generator object at the end as follows:

```
module.exports = {fn}
```

**Final Revised Code**

So now the two modules are as follows:

*app1.js*

```
var app = require('./app');
var one = 1;
var gen = app.fn(one); // First correction made here

gen.next();
gen.next();
```

*app.js*

```
var fn = function* () {

     yield console.log(one);

     yield console.log('done');
}


module.exports = {fn}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  const fn = function* () {
    console.log(yield);
    yield;
    console.log('done');
  }

  const gen = fn();
  gen.next();
  gen.next(1); // 1
  gen.next(); // "done"
```

`yield` evaluates to whatever you pass into `next()`. You can't "share" variables, just values.

> I have tried passing one as a parameter in fn() as well as in function* (), but that didn't work.

That would work if you export the generator itself:

```
 const fn = function* (one) {
    yield console.log(one);
    yield console.log('done');
 }

 var gen = fn(1); 
 gen.next();  // 1
 gen.next(); // "done"
```

Comment: sorry but I tested your claims, and it seems to me that everything is wrong

Comment: No, its just that I missed an initial `gen.next()`

Comment: Okay but it'is unclear, I try to use 'hello' and it's do undefined

Answer (score 0):

generator function Arguments are okay for instanciation : 
pass 1 value with next is a bit strange

```js
const fn = function* (arg)
{
  let foo = arg

  foo += yield foo    // 1
  foo += yield foo    // 2
  foo += yield foo    // 3
}

var one = 'abc=>'

let gen = fn(one)

console.log(  gen.next('x') )
console.log(  gen.next('y') )
console.log(  gen.next('z') )
console.log(  gen.next('bye') )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important }
```